# UPDATE [COLUMN] SET NULL WHERE [COLUMN] = '' - Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

I have a staging table in SQL Server 2016 that imports all columns as `varchar`.

If I run the following `UPDATE` statement on column1, I get no errors on the first execution. I receive the the following error on the second execution though:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5,
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I get no errors when executing the same `UPDATE` statement on subsequent statement executions for updating blanks or '' to NULL on column2.

Is there something else in column1 that is subsequently receiving errors that I need to remove?

If I perform the UPDATE statement and copy the results to Notepad for Column1, nothing else shows.

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Table] 
SET [Column1] = NULL 
WHERE [Column1] = ''
```

I still get the error.

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Table] 
SET [Column2] = NULL 
WHERE [Column2] = ''
```

Here, there is no error.

Altering the datatypes afterwards produces no errors. So, this does not affect import into another table. But I want to understand what I am doing incorrectly in the `UPDATE` statements:

```
ALTER TABLE [Database].[dbo].[Column1] 
    ALTER COLUMN [Column1] DECIMAL(38,2)

ALTER TABLE [Database].[dbo].[Column2] 
    ALTER COLUMN [Column2] DATETIME
```

Commands completed successfully.

Comment: The error itself stats that you are trying to update NULL value by using non-varchar column in search condition using varchar value i.e. `''`. Change your search condition according to column datatype, it should work then.

Comment: @iVad -- Thanks! Sorry to be a pain. I am updating ''  or a blank / empty record to NULL in the staging table. Am I missing a piece of the logic on how this works?

Comment: Earlier (before `ALTER` command) your `[Column2]` datatype was of type numeric so when you are trying to fetch the records with string condition (using `''`), a SQL server has to check the values in each row. Since numeric is not compatible with varchar, it was throwing arithmetic conversion error. Now it is working because the datatype is changed to `DATETIME` which is compatible with varchar, so now your update statement works. Hope this helps !!!

Comment: @iVad

Sql Server

UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Table] SET [Column1] = NULL WHERE [Column1] = ''

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5

Comment: Please help us with the schema of your table. It will helps us to better understand your problem.